# how to position highcharts - highstock buttons properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I was just trying highstock sample chart with its sample data in the picture. i downloaded it with highstock library, it's in the basic-line folder under examples. I wanted to style its buttons and etc. Buttons are being partially displayed on each other.

[image]

I wanted to fix it by inputBoxWidth which i found here: [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.buttons)

It only made it worst by ruining upper right positioned input boxes. I want buttons to be as wide as i want and no problem with them. How can i achieve this?

*ps: I also wonder how to remove/edit elemnts that i circled in red. The link at bottom right side of the graph and button at above the "To: " input box. Because i cannot find them in my html file.

**edit**: i deleted link at bottom right side
**edit2**: i also deleted exporting button

And here is my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Highstock Example</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {

                  $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
                            // Create the chart
                            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


                                                       rangeSelector : {

                                                       buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                                                            fill: 'none',
                                                            stroke: 'none',
                                                            'stroke-width': 15,
                                                            style: {
                                                                color: '#039',
                                                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                                                            },
                                                            states: {
                                                                hover: {
                                                                },
                                                                select: {
                                                                    fill: '#039',
                                                                    style: {
                                                                        color: 'white'
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                       selected : 1,
                                                       buttons: [
                                                                 {
                                                                 // quarter button
                                                                 type: 'month',
                                                                 count: 3,
                                                                 text: 'Q'},
                                                                 // year button
                                                                 {
                                                                 type: 'year',
                                                                 count: 1,
                                                                 text: 'Y'},
                                                                 // ytd button
                                                                 {
                                                                 type: 'ytd',
                                                                 text: 'YTD'},
                                                                 // all button
                                                                 {
                                                                 type: 'all',
                                                                 text: 'ALL'}]
                                                       },

                                                       title : {
                                                       text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
                                                       },

                                                       series : [{
                                                                 name : 'AAPL',
                                                                 data : data,
                                                                 tooltip: {
                                                                 valueDecimals: 2
                                                                 }
                                                                 }]
                                                       });
                            });

                  });

                </script>
            </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/Users/ihtechnology/Desktop/IH57/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/ihtechnology/Desktop/IH57/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [buttons theme](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.buttonTheme) and set width in that way:

```
buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                width:40,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLGH9/